# Get last line from a string

Tags: c++, string

I have currently implemented this logic to get the last line from a string. I am sure this is not the efficient solution.

```
...
string response;
while (1) {
    string newResponse = SocketRead();
    response += newResponse;

    if(checkIfReceiveComplete(response)) {
        break;
    }
}
...

bool checkIfReceiveComplete(string &response) {
   size_t index = response.find_last_of("\r\n");
   if (response+ 1 == response.length()) {
       response.pop_back();
       response.pop_back();
       index = response.find_last_of("\r\n");
   }
   string lastLine = response.substr(index + 1);

   return (lastLine.find(" OK ") != string::npos);
}
```

Kindly let me know how efficiently this can be implemented.

Note: I am not reading from a file. So I am not sure if can use seekg().

Comment: `abort()` will give the same results as your algorithm for some inputs (for example, those that don't contain newlines at all). Is it efficient enough?

Comment: Seriously though, it would be a *tad* more efficient to break up the input stream to lines at the source. Scan every buffer you read for `\r\n`, produce a vector of strings. Piece of cake.

Comment: @niklaz I am not doing file reading operation. How will be able to use seekg() to go to last line in a string of million lines or million (\n)?

Comment: @RamKishore Are you really reading 1 million lines into a `string`? This seems hard to belive, if each line is only 20 chars long, then your string would take up 20mb ... I feel like it would be hard to have a string of that size in the program.

Comment: @FantasticMrFox sorry my bad, million (10,25,580) is the length of the input string and number of lines is 15,807 to be precise.

Comment: how long is the buffer size for every socket read is it constant??

Comment: @Anil Buffer size is 8192, the length of the response string that I receive is not constant. It varies.

Comment: Its length varies randomly or due to any specific reason because usually we only receive less then requested data if there is not enough data to be sent over and that would be the case when you receive your last line

Comment: I mean by varying length is that, the final response length is not 10,25,580 always. Sometimes more than that, sometimes less.

Comment: So in the step where you read a string from socket its length should be equal to buffer size unless we have received the last line right? So if that is the case then no need to search every time just only if you receive string shorter the buffer size. Also if its size is same and last charechtar  is "\r\n"' then also you have to search else just add

Comment: @Anil that would work, but still checking the length() of the string is still taking almost the same time as the length() iterates through all the characters till the end to determine the length of the string.

Comment: One more thing that can be done is if you are using TCP then read command return number of characters read you check for it there itself and there will be no need query for length of string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`std::string`  stores a `char*` inside, which is consecutive in space, thus easy to access. We can use that to search from the back for the last (or second last) return character:

```
inline bool is_return(const char& input)
{
    return input == '\n' || input == '\r';
}

string last_line (const string& input)
{
    if(input.length() == 1) return input;
    size_t position = input.length()-2; // last character might be a return character, we can jump over it anyway
    while((not is_return(input[position])) and position > 0) position--;
    // now we are at the \n just before the last line, or at the first character of the string
    if(is_return(input[position])) position += 1;
    // now we are at the beginning of the last line

    return input.substr(position);
}
```

This code assumes that the input is really big while the output (/size of the last line) isn't. Doesn't use any special STL functions, might be that there are some nice tricks there, but should work.

One improvement might be to access some block ahead when the position is decremented in order to pre-load several chunks of data into the cache. Not sure about how this is done ideally, if this has a strong impact or is even necessary, maybe somebody else can elaborate. Not necessary if the assumption that the last line is small holds.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Will this be efficient than find_last_of() funtion that I have used?

Comment: @RamKishore The efficiency of it is in O(M), with M being the length of the last line rather than the length of the whole string. There shouldn't be a better time unless you have some way of predicting that length. Comparison with `find_last_of` is somewhat hard, see http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/find_last_of/, "Complexity: Unspecified, but generally up to linear in the string length (or pos) times the number of characters to match (worst case)". I'd assume that `find_last_of` searches the string from the beginning, thus requiring O(N) for N being the length of the string.

Comment: @RamKishore In any case, you already have the code for both methods, why don't you simply try it out with some realistic example of yours? Maybe with using `std::chrono::high_resolution_clock` to measure the time precisely?

Comment: Thanks for the info. Understood the difference. I thought find_last_of would start from the reverse. Thanks for clarifying.

Comment: @RamKishore I don't know if it does, might be. Don't know the implementation details of it. Again, try it out and compare. If it does, there is not really any room for improvement.

Answer (score 0):

@Aziuth, Improvement to the code, for scenarios where both "\r\n" are used to terminate a line. Just add this one line of code before the while loop: if(input[position]=='\n'|| input[position] == '\r') position--;//Just in case both \r\n are used at the line end

So, the new code should look like this:

```
inline bool is_return(const char& input)
{
    return input == '\n' || input == '\r';
}

string last_line (const string& input)
{
    if(input.length() == 1) return input;
    size_t position = input.length()-2; // last character might be a return character, we can jump over it anyway
    if(input[position]=='\n'|| input[position] == '\r')position--;//Just in case both \r\n are used at the line end
    while((not is_return(input[position])) and position > 0) position--;
    // now we are at the \n just before the last line, or at the first character of the string
    if(is_return(input[position])) position += 1;
    // now we are at the beginning of the last line

    return input.substr(position);
}
```